# Passing parameters from JSP to controller - Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jsp, parameters, controller

I have a little problem when I want to pass parameter to my controller. 
I have one method in controller:

`@RequestMapping("/redirect")`

```
public String print(String type, HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
{
    String path = "redirect:" + servletRequest.getParameter("type");
    return path;
}
```

And I have some buttons in my jsp file:

```
<form method="post" action="/WWP/redirect">
<button onclick=" <input type="text" name="type" value="/developer"/>">Developer</button>

<button onclick=<input type="text" name="type" value="/graphic"/>>Graphic</button>

<button onclick=" <input type="text" name="type" value="/cleaner"/>">Cleaner</button>
</form>
```

In this way I have 3 buttons and when for example I press Developer button variable "type" is "/developer" and I'm sending it to controller. But now my buttons look like this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/buttonspx.png/

It works correct, but I can't get rid this HTML tag and it's really nervous. How to do this? Or how send value to controller in different way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of normal buttons you can have submit buttons and handle them in controller as below

```
 <input type="submit" value="Developer" name="developer"></input>       
 <input type="submit" value="Graphic" name="graphic"></input>
 <input type="submit" value="Cleaner" name="cleaner"></input>
```

And you can have different methods in the controller class for each of the buttons clicked using the `params` attribute like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, params = "developer")
public ModelAndView developerMethod(){
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, params = "graphic")
public ModelAndView graphicMethod(){
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, params = "cleaner")
public ModelAndView cleanerMethod(){
}
```